# Is this procedure correct for determining linear independence over $\mathbb C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to show that the following set of vectors are linearly dependent over $\mathbb C$.
$(1-i, i)$ and $(2, -1+i)$.

If l multiply the first vector by $a+bi$ and the second vector by $c+di$, l will obtain four equations after combining the real part and imaginary parts together. Their sum will be equal to zero , l will get 4 equations. So if l write them into an augmented matrice and show that the rank is less than 4 (it is 2), hence prove that $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are not equal to zero or that the solution is non trivial. Will this procedure be correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but what about simply checking whether or not $\frac2{1-i}=\frac{-1+i}i$? The answer is affirmative (both quotients are equal to $1+i$) and therefore the vectors are linearly dependent.

What I am using here is the fact that two vectors are linearly dependent if and only if one of them is a multiple of the other one.

Comment: Thanks ,got it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a matrix whose columns are the above vectors and compute the determinant. If the determinant if non-zero, they are linearly independent and if it is zero they are linearly dependent. Alternatively you can use Gaussian elimination (here: [Linear Independence of a set of Complex Vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194987/linear-independence-of-a-set-of-complex-vectors))

Comment: I haven't used the determinant method, what is the reasoning behind that ?

Comment: If the determinant is zero then the column vectors are linearly dependent because one vector will be a multiple of another or when you reduce the matrix to row echelon form, there will be a zero row. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499321/why-is-the-determinant-zero-iff-the-column-vectors-are-linearly-dependent)